# SQL Server Pivot on Multiple columns and dynamic column names

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I am trying to pivot on multiple columns and have dynamic column names in the result. I am using SQL server 2014.

The original data looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE #s (grp varchar(3), id varchar(4), acc varchar(5), pr float, pos_live float,  pos_yest float, fnd varchar(2))

INSERT INTO #s Values ('GR1','VX1','CFD01',25,100,95,'KY')
INSERT INTO #s Values ('GR1','VX1','UCD01',24.5,30,20,'UC')
INSERT INTO #s Values ('GR1','VX1','US1',25,10,95,'US')
INSERT INTO #s Values ('GR1','VX2','CFD01',20,10,10,'KY')
INSERT INTO #s Values ('GR1','VX2','UCD01',19,5,5,'UC')
INSERT INTO #s Values ('GR1','FVS1','CFD01',24,1,1,'KY')
INSERT INTO #s Values ('GR1','FVS1','UCD01',23,1,1,'UC')
INSERT INTO #s Values ('GR1','FVS1','EU1',23.5,1,1,'EU')
INSERT INTO #s Values ('GR2','FVS1','CFD02',24,10,10,'KY')
INSERT INTO #s Values ('GR2','FVS1','UCD02',23,10,10,'UC')
INSERT INTO #s Values ('GR2','FVS1','EU2',23.5,10,10,'EU')
```

[image]

And I would like to get this

[image]

I am struggling to use the pivot function on multiple columns and additionaly display dynamic column names in the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really want to use `PIVOT` here explicitly because it is meant to pivot *one* column, not multiple. Conditional aggregation like in @D-Shih's answer is the way you want to go, except you can't do that if you expect the query to change with the data. So you can use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @s0  nvarchar(max) = N'',
        @s1  nvarchar(max) = N'', 
        @s2  nvarchar(max) = N'', 
        @s3  nvarchar(max) = N'', 
        @sql nvarchar(max) = N'';

;WITH cols AS 
(
  SELECT fnd, efnd = char(39) + fnd + char(39) FROM #s
)
SELECT @s0 += N',
   acc_' + fnd + N'     '
            + N' = MAX(CASE fnd WHEN ' + efnd 
            + N' THEN acc      END)',
       @s1 += N',
   pr_' + fnd + N'      '
            + N' = SUM(CASE fnd WHEN ' + efnd 
            + N' THEN pr       ELSE 0 END)',
       @s2 += N',
   pos_live_' + fnd 
            + N' = SUM(CASE fnd WHEN ' + efnd 
            + N' THEN pos_live ELSE 0 END)',
       @s3 += N',
   pos_yest_' + fnd 
            + N' = SUM(CASE fnd WHEN ' + efnd 
            + N' THEN pos_yest ELSE 0 END)'
FROM cols GROUP BY fnd, efnd;

SET @sql += N'SELECT grp, id' + @s0 + @s1 + @s2 + @s3 + N'
FROM #s GROUP BY grp, id ORDER BY grp;';
          
PRINT @sql;
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

Print output:

```
SELECT grp, id,
   acc_EU      = MAX(CASE fnd WHEN 'EU' THEN acc      END),
   acc_KY      = MAX(CASE fnd WHEN 'KY' THEN acc      END),
   acc_UC      = MAX(CASE fnd WHEN 'UC' THEN acc      END),
   acc_US      = MAX(CASE fnd WHEN 'US' THEN acc      END),
   pr_EU       = SUM(CASE fnd WHEN 'EU' THEN pr       ELSE 0 END),
   pr_KY       = SUM(CASE fnd WHEN 'KY' THEN pr       ELSE 0 END),
   pr_UC       = SUM(CASE fnd WHEN 'UC' THEN pr       ELSE 0 END),
   pr_US       = SUM(CASE fnd WHEN 'US' THEN pr       ELSE 0 END),
   pos_live_EU = SUM(CASE fnd WHEN 'EU' THEN pos_live ELSE 0 END),
   pos_live_KY = SUM(CASE fnd WHEN 'KY' THEN pos_live ELSE 0 END),
   pos_live_UC = SUM(CASE fnd WHEN 'UC' THEN pos_live ELSE 0 END),
   pos_live_US = SUM(CASE fnd WHEN 'US' THEN pos_live ELSE 0 END),
   pos_yest_EU = SUM(CASE fnd WHEN 'EU' THEN pos_yest ELSE 0 END),
   pos_yest_KY = SUM(CASE fnd WHEN 'KY' THEN pos_yest ELSE 0 END),
   pos_yest_UC = SUM(CASE fnd WHEN 'UC' THEN pos_yest ELSE 0 END),
   pos_yest_US = SUM(CASE fnd WHEN 'US' THEN pos_yest ELSE 0 END)
FROM #s GROUP BY grp, id ORDER BY grp;
```

Execution results:

> | grp | id | acc_EU | acc_KY | acc_UC | acc_US | pr_EU | pr_KY | pr_UC | pr_US | pos_live_EU | pos_live_KY | pos_live_UC | pos_live_US | pos_yest_EU | pos_yest_KY | pos_yest_UC | pos_yest_US |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | GR1 | FVS1 | EU1 | CFD01 | UCD01 | *null* | 23.5 | 24 | 23 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
> | GR1 | VX1 | *null* | CFD01 | UCD01 | US1 | 0 | 25 | 24.5 | 25 | 0 | 100 | 30 | 10 | 0 | 95 | 20 | 95 |
> | GR1 | VX2 | *null* | CFD01 | UCD01 | *null* | 0 | 20 | 19 | 0 | 0 | 10 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 10 | 5 | 0 |
> | GR2 | FVS1 | EU2 | CFD02 | UCD02 | *null* | 23.5 | 24 | 23 | 0 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 0 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 0 |

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/markdown?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fbb5b0d26823a5fd0468458df9e89612)

Comment: This works perfectly. I am now trying to add the acc value as well to get the result below. I tried to you use STUFF with FOR XML without success and I cannot use STRING_AGG because it is not available in SQL SERVER 2014.



grp id acc_KY acc_UC acc_US acc_EU pr_KY  pr_UC pr_US pr_EU
GR1 VX1 CFD01 UCD01 US1 NULL 25 24.5 25 NULL
GR1 VX2 CFD01 UCD01 NULL NULL 20 19 NULL NULL

Comment: I edited my orignal question with the added columns

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use condition aggregate function to make it, `SUM` with `CASE WHEN`

```
SELECT grp,
       id,
       SUM(CASE WHEN fnd = 'KY'THEN pr ELSE 0 END) pr_ky,
       SUM(CASE WHEN fnd = 'UC'THEN pr ELSE 0 END) pr_uc,
       SUM(CASE WHEN fnd = 'US'THEN pr ELSE 0 END) pr_us,
       SUM(CASE WHEN fnd = 'EU'THEN pr ELSE 0 END) pr_eu,
       SUM(CASE WHEN fnd = 'KY'THEN pos_live ELSE 0 END),
       SUM(CASE WHEN fnd = 'UC'THEN pos_live ELSE 0 END),
       SUM(CASE WHEN fnd = 'US'THEN pos_live ELSE 0 END),
       SUM(CASE WHEN fnd = 'EU'THEN pos_live ELSE 0 END),
       SUM(CASE WHEN fnd = 'KY'THEN pos_yest ELSE 0 END),
       SUM(CASE WHEN fnd = 'UC'THEN pos_yest ELSE 0 END),
       SUM(CASE WHEN fnd = 'US'THEN pos_yest ELSE 0 END),
       SUM(CASE WHEN fnd = 'EU'THEN pos_yest ELSE 0 END)
FROM #s
GROUP BY grp,id
ORDER BY grp
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=63bba48a469b40542c694528abe367b0)

Comment: I thought about that but the problem is that in the future I will have more values in the column "fnd" which will make the query difficult to maintain. This is the reason why I would like to find a way using the pivot function instead.

Comment: This is definitely the way to go vs. PIVOT, but it needs to be dynamic in order to meet the additional requirement (@Manuel you should add that requirement to the question).